# PHP preg_split Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, preg-split

please refer to the code below.

```
$dArr = '<script>document.write(volunteerDist);</script>';
```

$dArr gets the value of volunteerDist. echo $dArr prints the value 4.1,9.4,2.3,4.7,9.1,14.7,3.2,7.1,4.1,0.5

I wanted to split this into elements in an Array so I used:

```
$dArr = preg_split("/,/", $dArr);
```

But $dArr is an array with only one element, which is all of the values.. meaning no preg_split took place. I also tried

```
$temp=explode(",", $dArr);
```

but still did not work.

I tried to paste the value (i.e. the numbers above) and preg_split it directly

```
$temp=explode(",", '4.1,9.4,2.3,4.7,9.1,14.7,3.2,7.1,4.1,0.5');
```

and it was successful. What is wrong? TAKE NOTE that when I echo $dArr, the numbers are printed.

Comment: First off, if you're only splitting on the `,` you should use `explode()` anyway. The performance loss of `preg_split()` is negligible, but if you're doing this is any sort of iteration, you may as well benefit from the brevity and speed of `explode()`.

Comment: Works fine for me http://codepad.org/ooeOHHz4

Comment: No, echo $dArr prints the <script> tag, the browser then renders that as your list of numbers. View source on the page and you'll see what I mean. You can't use Javascript within PHP this way.

Comment: Im pretty sure your first line is going to fail .... the code to the right of `=` is executed on the front end ... have you checked `$dArr` is not empty ???

Comment: Are you expecting that JavaScript code to run when the PHP is executing so you get the numbers?

Comment: but echo $dArr returned the numbers!

Comment: look everybody, when I echo out $dArr, the numbers printed out. so i don't think there is something with the execution of javascript and php, right?

Comment: when you echo $dArr, the browser sees a script tag, and executes it, and writes the contents of `volunteerDist` in the page. This all takes place AFTER php sent the page to the browser. How is `volunteerDist`computed in the first place ?

Comment: quick tip: use var_dump($someThing) to test what is inside a variable, especially if it is acting strange

Comment: volunteerDist is computed on the distance of all the users of my system to a specified event. for example, there is a fire in Restaurant A, volunteerDist will contain all the distance of the volunteer from Restaurant A computed through Google Maps

Comment: var_dump($dArr) returned string(47) "4.1,9.4,2.3,4.7,9.1,14.7,3.2,7.1,4.1,0.5"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing server side and client side code and logic here.

You see the "correct" output because of the `document.write` method that writes the output to the browser.

You can't interact directly with client side variable in a server side code.

You will have to either use AJAX to send the client side value to the server, or parse it in the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dArr = volunteerDist.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < dArr.length; i++)
   document.write(dArr[i] + "<br />");
</script>
```

Edit: although I'm not PHP developer, reading some other posts gave me enough sample codes.

To send the value of the client side `volunteerDist` variable to PHP and save to database, first of all include jQuery in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now have this somewhere after the variable is defined and created:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourpagehere.php",
    data: "volunteerDist=" + volunteerDist,
    dataType: "html"
});
</script>
```

And to read this data and add to database:

```
<?php
    $volunteerDist = $_POST['volunteerDist'];
    if(isset($volunteerDist)) {
        $dArr = preg_split("/,/", $volunteerDist);
        foreach($dArr as $volunteer) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (fieldname) VALUES ('".$volunteer."')";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>
```

Of course, you need to change the page name, table name and field name to your real values.

Comment: var_dump($dArr) returned string(47) "4.1,9.4,2.3,4.7,9.1,14.7,3.2,7.1,4.1,0.5" so that means $dArr already got the data.. i need to use it in php because i need to insert them in my databse

Comment: Right. Count the character in `<script>document.write(volunteerDist);</script>` = exactly 47. When **sent to the browser** it will show the value in the **client side variable** `volunteerDist`. Change the string to: `$dArr = '<script>alert(volunteerDist);</script>';` and maybe you will see what I'm trying to say all along.

Comment: To insert this to database you will have to use AJAX. Look for jQuery AJAX it's the most simple and friendly way - include the jQuery basic library then with one line you can send the value to your PHP code.

Comment: okay okay.. so how can I transfer the values into my php code for insertion in mysql?

Comment: Like I said, jQuery AJAX is the most simple way.

Comment: @Brandon sure, see the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639261/jquery-php-insert-data-into-mysql-without-form). In your case it just should be `data: volunteerDist`

Comment: what does adduser.php contain?

Comment: That page should contain the relevant code that put the data into database. you don't have to create new page just for this, you can also post to the same page you have already and check if you get any data.

Comment: i do not know how to retrieve data from the same page.. i need to see actual coding here

Comment: @Brandon [here is something I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819699/how-to-insert-form-data-into-mysql-database-table-with-php-and-ajax) with PHP code that read POST data and insert to database.

Comment: @BrandonYoung OK, edited my post with as much as I can do. Hope this help, can't really think of anything else I can do to help.

Comment: is this all in just one file?

Comment: @Brandon yes the same file holding the code you originally posted in your question here.

Comment: what are the reasons that it enters in error and complete functions? it alerts "nope" and "thanks"

Comment: @BrandonYoung sorry, can't undertstand what you mean. "nope" and "thanks"??

Comment: hmm on the link that you gave.. 
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "validatedata.php",
                data : ({
                    polltitle:nameVal,
                    answerone:optVal1,
                }),
                success: function(){
                     alert("worked");
                    },
               error :function(){
                    alert("nope :( ");
               },
               complete : function(){
                   alert("thanks");
               }
                 });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8933/discussion-between-brandon-young-and-shadow-wizard)